# getElementsByAttribute() is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following code to get an element by it's attribute:

```
document.getElementsByAttribute("xlink:href",id);
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByAttribute is not a function

I don't understand what's going wrong, is it not a standard chrome function?

Comment: should it not be `document.getElementsByAttribute("id",id);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/getElementsByAttribute):

> Note that this method is only available on XUL elements; it is not part of the W3C DOM.

Use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[xlink|href='"+id+"']");
```

Answer (score 10):

> Is it not a chrome standard function?

No, it isn't.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Method/getElementsByAttribute):

> Note that this method is only available on XUL elements; it is not part of the W3C DOM.

Consider using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [an attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In the console you will get something like this:
**Example text.[Do anything...]

Example text.[Do anything...]**

But in your browser you will get everything.
**Try in your Browser.**
*[You will get something like this in your browser's console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb48d.png)*

```js
let elements = (() => {
  let aa = document.querySelectorAll('*')
  let bb = []
  aa.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.getAttribute('Otag')) bb.push(el)
  })
  return bb
})();
console.log(elements); //You should get all the HTML elements containing that [attr] attribute in an array
```

```html
<div attr="aa">Example text.[Do anything...]</div>
<div attr="bb">Example text.[Do anything...]</div>
```